# Simplify jQuery operation

Tags: jquery

I'm very rusty with jQuery and could use some advice.

--

```
(function($) {

  "use strict";

  var $navPrimary   = $('.nav__primary'),
      $navSecondary = $('.nav__secondary'),
      $navClose     = $('.nav__close');

  // Primary navigation
  $('.nav__primary__toggle').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    reset();

    if (!$navPrimary.hasClass('nav__primary--open')) {
      $navPrimary.addClass('nav__primary--open');
    }

  });

  // Secondary navigation
  $('.nav__secondary__toggle').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    reset();

    if (!$navSecondary.hasClass('nav__secondary--open')) {
      $navSecondary.addClass('nav__secondary--open');
    }

  });


  // Navigation close
  $('.nav__primary__close, .nav__secondary__close').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    reset();

  });


  // Navigation reset
  var reset = function() {

    if ($navPrimary.hasClass('nav__primary--open')) {
      $navPrimary.removeClass('nav__primary--open');
    }

    if ($navSecondary.hasClass('nav__secondary--open')) {
      $navSecondary.removeClass('nav__secondary--open');
    }

  }

})(jQuery);
```

--

The only real difference is in the class names. One of the navigation's being the primary navigation and the other being the secondary navigation.

The navigation toggles however sit outside of the navigation elements.

Any direction would be brilliant.

Thanks

Comment: String concatenation.

Comment: just a note, you don't need the `if`s in `reset()`, they'r redundant. just remove the class anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a function and string concatenation:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    setupNav("primary");
    setupNav("secondary");

    function setupNav(navType) {
        var $nav = $(".nav__" + navType);

        $('.nav__' + navType + '__toggle').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            reset();

            $nav.addClass('nav__' + navType + '--open');
        });

        $('.nav__' + navType + '__close').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            reset();
        });
    }

    function reset() {
        $('.nav__primary').removeClass('nav__primary--open');
        $('.nav__secondary').removeClass('nav__secondary--open');
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Also, unless you have multiple elements that match `.nav__primary` or `.nav__secondary`, you don't need the `hasClass` check (and with *just* the code in your question, you don't need it even if there are multiple elements), so I've left it out above.

You'd only need the `hasClass` check if there were multiple matching elements where some might have the class and others might not, and you wanted to to add/remove the class from the others based on whether the *first* one had the class.